# How to select a value from dropdown developed using div tag using Selenium and Python?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

In Selenium Java we are using ACTION class method or SELECT method to select value from drop down.

Is there a similar method in Python?

Comment: Is it a div that looks like a dropdown, or is it a real <select> tag? and how would you automate this in Java?

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been already clarified please have a look here:

[Selecting combobox option with a div tag using Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39471097/selecting-a-combobox-option-with-a-div-tag-using-selenium-and-python)

Comment: I think that linked answer is confusing, because the question is not about a Select, but about a dropdown that looks like a select.

Comment: Hmm maybe the question is also confusing, as the title talks about a div, but the question about ACTION and SELECTs.

Comment: Sorry Niels, that didn´t understand the question. My first understanding was about dropdown that looks like a select...sorry in this case I cannot help. Cheers..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to read the documetation for the Selenium Python package? See: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html

Code example from the documentation:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('name'))
select.select_by_index(index)
select.select_by_visible_text("text")
select.select_by_value(value)
```